# Undefined error getting parents childs input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td class="packing-vol">0.19</td>
       <td class="qty-cell"><input type="text" name="qty[]" class="qty" value="2" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td class="packing_total">0.70</td>
       <td class="qty-cell"><input type="text" name="qty[]" class="qty" value="1" /></td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

I'm looping through each occurence of .packing-vol getting it's text, then I want to get the qty from the same row so I go up to it's parent then drill into the .qty class. But when I alert(qty) i get 'undefined' message.

```
var total = 0;

jQuery('.packing-vol').each(function(i) {

    var qty = jQuery(this).parent("td.qty-cell .qty").val();
    alert(qty);

    var cur = parseFloat(jQuery(this).text());
    if(!isNaN(cur)){
        total = total + cur;
    }

});
```

Comment: Which parent of a `.packing-vol` is a `td` with class `qty-cell`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parent` is just one level upwards. You can't use it to go inside trees again.

`parents` is multiple levels upwards. You can't use it to go inside trees again.

You can use `parent`/`parents` and then use `find` to do what you want, or even better:

```
var total = 0;
jQuery('.packing-vol').each(function(i) {

    var qty = jQuery(this).parent().children('.qty-cell').children('.qty').val();
    alert(qty);

    var cur = parseFloat(jQuery(this).text());
    if (!isNaN(cur)){
        total = total + cur;
    }
});
```

You could also use `find`, but it is **slower** than going directly inside, because it has to search the DOM object.

But you could also do:

```
var qty = jQuery(this).parent().find("td.qty-cell .qty").val();
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you should do this:

```
var qty = jQuery(this).parent().find("td.qty-cell .qty").val();
```

You need to go 1 level up (using `.parent`) and then find your field inside with `.find`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
var qty = jQuery(this).parent("td.qty-cell .qty").val();
```

Try:

```
var qty = jQuery(this).parent().find(".qty").val();
```